# How can you import M2E Maven projects into Eclipse from the command line?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I'm working on writing a script that will checkout multiple Maven projects that all have modules.  I want to import all the modules into Eclipse Mars as M2E projects.  Now I've scoured other questions and answers about this and only see Eclipse CDT based solutions (eclipse.exe -base workspace -importAll {someURI}).  However this doesn't convert your projects into M2E projects in eclipse.  They are just plain-Jane java projects.

Does anyone know how I can, from a Windows Batch Script, import Maven projects as M2E faceted projects in Eclipse Mars?

I'm using Eclipse Mars.1, Java 7, Maven 3.3.

ADDED:
Ultimately what I really want is a reliable way to build up a complex workspace of M2E projects.  There are hierarchical dependencies between them so if it's not done right it's very confusing for more Junior developers.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to share/manager complex workspaces?  Using command line tools isn't the only option.  I also looked into exporting a project set file (*.psf).  The problem I see there is that the projects loose the M2E configuration.

Comment: Are those Maven project correctly organised as a hierarchical directory structure? Is this a single project which is released at the same time? Is it stored in the same version control repository which means can you checkout it via single command (either via git clone or a single svn checkout URL...) ? Are you stuck with the Eclipse Release ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This will generate eclipse configuration files, after of that you can import into eclipse:

```
eclipse.exe -base workspace -importAll {someURI}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it only creates Java projects in Eclipse.  I want the projects to be M2E faceted projects because otherwise the workspace if filled with missing dependencies for hierarchical projects that have never been installed into the local repository.

Comment: Also, the eclipse plugin is now deprecated.  Maven officially recommends you use the M2E plugin to generate Eclipse project files.

Comment: I imagined that maybe using `mnv eclipse:eclipse` before importing would work. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) is the options that provide eclipse CDT, it seems that it doesn't support maven

Comment: At this stage I'm thinking it's best to design a solution around importing projects into eclipse using the File > Import > Existing Maven Projects.  That way you allow M2E to generate all the eclipse related files.

Comment: That seems to be the most appropriate way, even though the `mvn eclipse: eclipse` command creates the same configuration files as eclipse does when importing a maven project

Comment: `mvn eclipse:....` is long being marked as deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore...